# knockout event binding for touch events causing problems for scroll

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

While handling touchstart and touchmove using knockout event binding, scrolling gets stuck (no preventDefault) and also faced problem in getting click event.
Applying these events with jquery worked fine.
Is there some known bug of knockout or this is not how I should be doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout does `preventDefault` unless you tell it not to by having your event handler return `true`. See [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html#note-3-allowing-the-default-click-action):

> By default, Knockout will prevent the click event from taking any
>   default action. This means that if you use the click binding on an a
>   tag (a link), for example, the browser will only call your handler
>   function and will not navigate to the link’s href. This is a useful
>   default because when you use the click binding, it’s normally because
>   you’re using the link as part of a UI that manipulates your view
>   model, not as a regular hyperlink to another web page.
>
> However, if you do want to let the default click action proceed, just
>   return true from your click handler function.